# Pyqt default progress bar not scaling properly

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt4

I have just started with Pyqt, my OS is Lubuntu 12.04. I have created a progress bar in a empty window with the Qt designer, the problem is that it seems that it isnt scaling right.

When the values are between 0 and 2, the progress bar image is still there and looks ugly:

[image: 0%]
.

The start of the progress bar should be empty (or at least thats what I think)

I dont know if its OS related problem, or just I did something wrong. Any way to fix it?

Comment: This looks like a Qt drawing bug and should best be filed with the qt project's bug tracker. It may very well be an issue related to the theme. Try change the appearance with qtconfig and then have another look.

Comment: It seems to depend on the current widget-style in use. When previewed with the GTK+, Cleanlooks or Plastique styles, there is a tiny bar similar to the image above; but with the other styles, there isn't.